# Having scrolling issue when converting jQuery to Vanilla javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm converting this simple scrolling code from jQuery to vanilla Javascript but having small issues when selecting the elements. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's working jQuery code:

[**jQuery LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/qzc3ahev/4/)

Now here's my vanilla Javascript code:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.target').forEach(function(item, index){
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         document.querySelector('#nav nav a').classList.remove('active');
         document.querySelector('#nav nav a[href=#'+ id +']').classList.add('active');
     }
 });
});
```

Vanilla JavaScript Demo:

[**JavaScript DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/fpoh4kda/9/)

Comment: Did you look at the console?  The console is your friend.   jsfiddle even provides a console for you.  Look in the console.  It will help you, as it's your friend.  http://jsfiddle.net/7m6kbjvy/

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the binding by attribute **id** by making the binding by **index** (At my discretion):

```
document.querySelectorAll("#nav nav a")[index].classList.add("active");
```

Also, I inserted an internal `forEach()` to remove the *active* class everywhere, with the subsequent receipt of the *active* class for the **current** one.

`$(window).scrollTop()` replaced by `window.pageYOffset`;

`$(this).offset().top` replaced by `item.offsetTop`.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(".target").forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= item.offsetTop) {
            document.querySelectorAll("#nav nav a").forEach(function (a_del) {
                a_del.classList.remove("active");
            });
            document.querySelectorAll("#nav nav a")[index].classList.add("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Also, in your html, some covering `<div>` do not contain `/`, like a closed `</div>`. Like that:

```
<section id="main">
    <div class="target" id="1">TARGET 1</div>
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 1<div>   <===
    <div>item 1<div>   <===
    ...
```

Comment: Thank. you for your help mate!

Comment: @progx, no problem :)